# How do I make this cylinder wrap around this path?

Tags: shrinkwrap

I have this path. I want the yellow half cylinder to automatically follow my path. I tried to use Shrinkwrap but it doesn't find the path.
My end result should be that the cylinder is like the annotations I did.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

At its simplest, this could be your curve, set to 'Half' Fill Mode, using its native 'Round' bevel...

[image]

.. followed up with *Solidify*, *Bevel*, and *Subdivision Surface* modifiers

The curve can have a fairly nasty habit of flipping its twist.. I've found the most stable method has been to set the curve's 'Twist Method' to 'Minimum', as shown, construct the curve in in its XY, and adjust its tilt, throughout, to -90 degrees.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create a bezier curve,
Apply a curve modifier to your cylinder,  select your bezier curve as "curve object" under the curve modifier

Set the right Deform Axis
[image]

Make sure your cylinder has enough geometry to get wrap around the path

[image]

Comment: On top of that, a subdivision surface could also do well, an inset can be done on the top and bottom faces if there are there to prevent deformation.